# cpu-features.h no such file or directory webrtc Android build

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, webrtc

i am building webrtc for Android & i had followed following steps for generating webrtc library:

source build/android/envsetup.sh
python webrtc/build/gyp_webrtc
ninja -c out/Debug

this generates following error:

> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed. ninja: Entering directory
>   `./out/Release/' [3/2806] CC
>   obj/webrtc/system_wrappers/source/cpu_features_android.cpu_features_android.o
>   FAILED:
>   /home/rtcdev/Nishant/src/third_party/android_tools/ndk//toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>
> -MMD -MF obj/webrtc/system_wrappers/source/cpu_features_android.cpu_features_android.o.d
>
> -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DCLD_VERSION=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DNO_TCMALLOC -DDISABLE_NACL 
>           -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=233105-2 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_MEDIA_ROUTER=1 
>           -DUSE_PROPRIETARY_CODECS -DENABLE_BROWSER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS 
>           -DSYSTEM_NATIVELY_SIGNALS_MEMORY_PRESSURE -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DFIELDTRIAL_TESTING_ENABLED 
>           -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 
>           -DUSE_BROWSER_SPELLCHECKER=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DVIDEO_HOLE=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA 
>           -DENABLE_WEBVR -DMOBILE_SAFE_BROWSING -DSAFE_BROWSING_DB_REMOTE -DSAFE_BROWSING_SERVICE 
>           -DEXPAT_RELATIVE_PATH -DWEBRTC_MODULE_UTILITY_VIDEO -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM -DWEBRTC_ARCH_ARM_V7 
>           -DWEBRTC_DETECT_ARM_NEON -DWEBRTC_POSIX -DWEBRTC_LINUX -DWEBRTC_ANDROID -DWEBRTC_ANDROID_OPENSLES -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 
>           -DUSE_OPENSSL=1 -DUSE_OPENSSL_CERTS=1 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -DANDROID -D__GNU_SOURCE=1 
>           '-DCHROME_BUILD_ID=""' -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 
>           -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 
>           -Igen -I../.. 
>           -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -fno-strict-aliasing 
>           -Wall -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-unused-local-typedefs 
>           -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-strict-overflow -fno-builtin-cos -fno-builtin-sin 
>           -fno-builtin-cosf -fno-builtin-sinf -march=armv7-a -mtune=generic-armv7-a -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -mfloat-abi=softfp 
>           -mthumb -fno-tree-sra -fno-caller-saves -Wno-psabi -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables 
>           -g -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -finline-limit=64 
>           --sysroot=../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//platforms/android-16/arch-arm
>
> -isystem../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include
>
> -isystem../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/libcxxabi/include
>
> -isystem../../third_party/android_tools/ndk//sources/android/support/include
>
> -Os -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fomit-frame-pointer -funwind-tables
>           -c ../../webrtc/system_wrappers/source/cpu_features_android.c 
>           -o obj/webrtc/system_wrappers/source/cpu_features_android.cpu_features_android.o
>
> ../../webrtc/system_wrappers/source/cpu_features_android.c:11:26:
>   fatal error: cpu-features.h: No such file or directory  #include
>   
>   ^ compilation terminated.

Does Anyone have Any idea by seeing webrtc Flags, what i am missing for webrtc Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler could not find the header file cpu-features.h, so find out which directory it resides, and then add that directory to the compiler flags, just like the other directory you already have.